# Ginger plant growing into height

Tags: houseplants, plant-recommendations, ginger

I have 2 ginger bulbs planted and while the plants grow fast (it has grown from zero to this in about a month), they are getting very high. Right now nearing a meter. The plant is mostly on a windowsill that gets afternoon light. I took the picture elsewhere just to get a better image.

Could the windowsill be too intense with light? Although, I have to say, it almost never gets direct sun.

[image: Ginger]

Comment: This plant does not like direct sun anyway - dappled sunlight morning or evening is fine, but not full on sunlight. However, yours does appear to have not been receiving sufficient bright light, because it looks etiolated... it does better outside if you can move it out there, hardening off first. If you've had it indoors all the time in lowish light levels, that would explain it, along with, never mind, I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said which ginger this is - assuming its the type of ginger where the root is used for cooking, that plant does not like direct sunlight, though it appreciates dappled sun. Your plant looks a bit etiolated, so it's not been receiving sufficient bright daylight - the stems look a little weak, but lack of air movement could be contributing to that.

If you can increase its daylight levels without exposing it to hot sunlight between 11 and 3 in the afternoon, then stand it there, preferably near an open window to allow air movement. Otherwise, it may do better out of doors if your conditions are appropriate, but it will need hardening off first.

Comment: It is the cooking type of ginger, apologies for not mentioning it in the initial post.

I live on the west coast of Norway where temperatures hardly raise above 60 F degrees outside, and due to coastal weather, we mostly have grey/rainy weather, so I think keeping it inside for the most part is a better idea. But I agree, it does look etiolated, even though it stands in one of the brightest places in my flat.

I might try moving it outdoors during the summer months. It is on the good way to hardening it looks like. The stems are quite sturdy.

Thank you for your thorough movement

Comment: Ah,, that explains your keeping it indoors, and why light levels aren't high enough, too far north... hopefully it'll grow a good root anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a very healthy plant and no cause for concern. [They will eventually reach a height of 2 feet or more in a container, and may reach a height of 2-3 feet in the garden.](http://veggieharvest.com/herbs/ginger.html) It has probably reached its height limit now so if I were you I would return it to where it used to be and keep up the same good work.